# Error 406 in Spring MVC - migration from Spring 3.0.5 to Spring 4.2.4

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jackson

I am in the process of migrating a web-app from Spring 3.0.5 to 4.2.4. After many hurdles (apparently the process is not really documented well...), I've hit the dreaded 406 error. It seems there are many questions all around, but none of the answers are working (even the questionable ones).

This is the **controller** code with the function:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/echo", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=*/*")
@ResponseBody
public String echoReply(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    return "echo";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=*/*")
@ResponseBody
public boolean testFunc(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    ...
    return ...;
}
```

The first function returns `echo` as expected, but the test function returns error 406 - `Could not find acceptable representation`. The exact message is:

```
The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating
responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request
"accept" headers
```

Both are relevant to AJAX calls and to direct access via URL.

Any ideas what to look for and why it happens that way?

**Edit**: perhaps this is some issue in controller class annotations (something missing that should be in Spring 4.2)?

**app-context.xml**:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd" default-lazy-init="true">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
       <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="..." />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>

    // bunch of component-scans and some more beans

</beans>
```

**pom.xml**:
(relevant dependencies for Jackson)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Could you post the test function that is failing?

Comment: `return true;` does the same - that's why I didn't feel the need to write the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official Spring MVC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types) lists the following data types as valid return types for controller methods:

- `ModelAndView`
- `Model`
- `Map`
- `View`
- `String`
- `void`
- `HttpEntity`
- `HttpHeaders`
- `Callable`
- `DeferredResult`
- `ListenableFuture`
- `ResponseBodyEmitter`
- `SseEmitter`
- `StreamingResponseBody`

For a controller method annotated with `@ResponseBody` the return type is written to the response body.  This process is carried out using an `HttpMessageConverter` appropriate for the `Accepts` request header.

---

Since your `testFunc` method has a return type of `boolean`, Spring MVC will attempt to write the returned value using an `HttpMessageConverter`.  This means, the `Accepts` header must specify a value that will result in a valid representation of a `boolean` value.  Therefore, the representation can only be schemaless, such as JSON.  Any other representation will lead to the described error.

Therefore, if your `Accepts` header is set to `text/html` or `application/xml`, `boolean` will fail to get written to the response body.  If however you set the header to `application/json`, your `boolean` value will get written correctly.

If you want to support HTML and XML as well, you will have to wrap the `boolean` in an object such as a `Map` or a custom object.

Comment: Hmmm. Thank you for the answer, I will check it. Meanwhile, I checked the request and it has */* in the Accept header - shouldn't it support returning boolean? For the record - the same functions work as they are in Spring 3.0.5.

Comment: This is the accept of a basic URL request in Chrome: `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8`

Comment: None of these will allow returning a primitive from a controller method because there is no `MessageConverter` for primitives.  If you use a REST client like Postman and use `application/json` as the `Accept` header, you will see `boolean` values returned correctly as JSON will support primitives.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for the explanation - I will dig into all of this when I have the time. Will approve the answer when I test it (but it does make sense, I must admit).

Comment: For any who comes across this question - the explanation and solution by manish were indeed correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update `app-context.xml` with

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no - exactly the same. :\